# Editable linked cells in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I could scavenge the following bit of code:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G8")) Is Nothing Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Költségvetés").Range("H8").Value = Target.Value * 12
    End If 
End Sub
```

It works fine, however, I want to automatically enter the value of each cell times 12 from G8:G21 to H8:21, and also if I enter a value into H8:21 range it automatically enters the 1/12th of that value into G8:G21. So if either one get edited it automatically overwrites the other one as well.

Each cell should be "linked" to its neighbor, like G8 to H8 and so on.

How can I modify this bit of code to do my bidding?

Comment: Do you want saying "G8:H21" range, in fact? If not, please better define the range...

Comment: Please, test my answer code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example for the case in which both cols **G** and **H** are in the **same worksheet**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim H As Range, G As Range, v
    Set G = Range("G1:G21")
    Set H = Range("H1:H21")
    v = Target.Value

    If Intersect(Union(G, H), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Intersect(Target, H) Is Nothing Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = 12 * v
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = v / 12
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

*If the cols are not in the same worksheet, a separate macro would be required for each sheet.*

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, this code should work:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G8:H21")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            If Target.Column = 8 Then
                Target.Offset(, 1).value = Target.value / 12
            Else
                Target.Offset(, 1).value = Target.value * 12
            End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```